# LDAC support (macOS Monterey MacBook Pro M1)

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, ios, bluetooth

I'm using a Sony XM5 headphone. Is it possible to use LDAC as the bluetooth codec for my MacBook and iPhone?

Comment: Preliminary answer: no. Not unless Apple decide to add support, or if you purchase a USB bluetooth thingy with LDAC support.